# duktape: "TypeError: not callable"

Tags: duktape

```
duk> (function digits(x) { var _x = Math.abs(x); _x = Math.log10(_x);  return _x
;} ) (10)
```

> TypeError: not callable
>           duk_js_call.c:682
>           digits input:1
>           global input:1 preventsyield

Answer (score 2):

Math.log10() is not a standard part of Ecmascript E5/E5.1, and is not provided by Duktape.